# Updating variables in web.config outside appSettings

Tags: azure-devops

I need to update values in web.config in Azure TFS. I am able to get the value for connectionString replaced which is part of the appSettings (for this to work, I needed to enable the setting named XML variable substitution (under IIS Web Deploy).

However, there are other areas within web.config which do not get replaced.

I have tried several different approaches, using different tasks for token replacement, using the "Release" or "Environment" setting for variables, using variable groups. However, none of these worked.

Currently I am using the Replace tokens task (available at https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task#readme )

I have set the Token Prefix and Suffix to __ (to match with what is web.config)

Here is an extract of the web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ConnectionString" value="__ConnectionString__"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <pages theme="__Theme__" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>       
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="TestBinding1">
                    <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    </textMessageEncoding>
                    <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
            __basicHttpBindingOptionalBinding__
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="__TestEndPoint__" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="TestBinding1" contract="BSEInspectionsWebServiceForFDA.StateDataTransfer" name="StateDataTransferPort" />
            __endpointOptionalEndpoint__
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I expect only blank lines for basicHttpBindingOptionalBinding and endpointOptionalEndpoint. The **Theme** needs to be replaced with TestTheme and TestEndPoint needs to be set with the value defined in variables.

Comment: UPDATE: I have solved this using this method. (I think this is not ideal but it works for now). Added an extension "RegEx Find & Replace". For each variable, I invoked this extension (e.g. __ConnectionString__ is replaced with the variable value for the release). Like wise for __Theme__, __basicHttpBindingOptionalBinding__, __TestEndPoint__ and __endpointOptionalEndpoint__.

Answer (score 1):

Add a parameters.xml to your project, as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/configuring-parameters-for-web-package-deployment

specify parameter there, for example, "myEndpointAddress".

Then in IIS Web Deploy Task use additional arguments to pass the value
-setParam:name='myEndPointAddress',value='new_value'

Comment: Currently, this answer relies heavily on information contained in the link—which means it will be hard to follow if/when Microsoft changes the URL to that link. To help keep this relevant in the future, can you edit your answer to include the relevant details of how to add `parameters.xml` to a project?

Answer (score 0):

For replacing `__Theme__, __TestEndPoint__`, I recommend extension task [Magic Chunks](https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/magic-chunks).

You can install Magic Chunks task to your organization and add it to your pipeline. It tested your web.config with below example settings for magic chunk task:[image]

For replacing **basicHttpBindingOptionalBinding** , i recommend another extension task [RegEx Find & Replace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=knom.regexreplace-task&targetId=47097972-e633-4284-ad72-fe49f3c8dd5f)

[image]

You can reference your pipeline variables in both the tasks. I added above two tasks to my test pipeline. The values in web.config was replaced successfully.

**Update**: To extract the web.config from the build artifacts using powershell task to run below scripts:

You need to config `$sourceFile` and `$destFile` yourself. `$sourceFile` should be the absolute path to zip file.

```
$sourceFile="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AboutSite.zip"
$destFile="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\web.config"

Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
$zip = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($sourceFile)
$zip.Entries | where {$_.Name -like 'web.config'} | foreach {[System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($_, $destFile, $true)}
$zip.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thank you! By $(myaddress) are you referring to the value of a variable defined in the build?

Comment: My bad- just noticed that you have already mentioned using Pipeline variables in both the tasks.

Comment: I guess I am missing something. I added "Magic Chunks" extension and it seems to be working. However, I do not see the results in the deployment. Giving the steps that I have added - 
`####[section]Starting: Release  
`####[section]Starting: Initialize job  
`####[section]Starting: Download artifact - _ Build - drop  
`####[section]Starting: Config transform - **\web.config  
`####[section]Starting: IIS Web App Manage  
`####[section]Starting: IIS Web App Deploy  
`####[section]Starting: Finalize Job

Comment: you can go to your build pipeline to check if the artifact is packaged to a single zip file. If it is a zip file, it needs to be unzipped before config transform. Or the web config file can not be detected.

Comment: As of now I have used a workaround where I am copying another web.config (using an inline powershell script). I was wondering if I could do the replacement of the variables after the package is unzipped and deployed so that I don't need to unzip (otherwise the unzip will be run two times).

Comment: @Sk-USA, I think you can use Kudu API to do the replacement after the deployment. Please check my update.

Comment: I am not sure if we are on the same page here. I have been able to replace the web.config file with another file. However, I will try out different approaches and keep you posted. 

I truly appreciate your help and attention.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share screenshots for Unzip task? I tried unzip using this extension task https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YodLabs.UnzipTask. 

I specified "Zip file path": $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\Build.WebUI.zip  and 

"Extract Pattern Filter":
**/web.config

and "Destination folder":
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\_Build 

I get this error
unzipping C:\azagent\A5\_work\r2\a\**\Build.WebUI.zip using pattern **/web.config to folder C:\azagent\A5\_work\r2\a\_Build

2019-11-18T16:36:13.7580216Z ##[error]zip file not found

Comment: My apologies - however, I think this is to do with the edit function in SO - repeating the line below - (I have put this as code line - so should display correctly now)

`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) \**\USAPlants.WebUI.zip`

`unzipping C:\azagent\A5\_work\r2\a\**\USAPlants.WebUI.zip using pattern **/web.config to folder C:\azagent\A5\_work\r2\a\_USA Plants Build`

Comment: I failed to make unzip task working even if i specified the exact zip file path, i cannot figure out what is the right `extract pattern filter`. I end up writing a powershell script to extract the web.config. I updated my powershell script to above answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out - I keep thinking that Azure is making this far harder than it should be ....

Comment: When you responded initially - you mentioned that you got the web.config replacement to work using MagicChunks - at that time - how did you accomplish that?

Comment: I finally got this working! Here is what I did 
a. Used a PowerShell script to copy web.config to a temp folder
b. Used the RegEx find and Replace extension for replacing each variable (I had to use the extenstion 5 times once for each var)
c. Copy web.config from temp folder back to the website.

Before this, I tried 
a. Unzip - I customized your script as my package contains more than web.config file. I got it work in my local however, got an error in the server.
b. using MagicChunks, however, I noticed that it inserts a duplicate set of lines in the file. Thank you for everything.

Comment: Here is the error that I got during Unzip
Unable to find type [IO.Compression.sourceFile]. Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded.