# Run integration test in build pipeline with transformed appsettings

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, xunit

I added an integration test project in my Solution, using .NET Core 3.1 and xUnit. In this test project I also added an appsettings.json with a connectionstring that should be used locally.

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDb;Initial Catalog=MyApp_IntegrationTests;Integrated Security=True"
  }
```

I also added the following in my build pipeline in Azure DevOps:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Run integration tests'
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Tests.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

This fails because Azure does not support LocalDB. This makes sense, but i can't figure out how to transform the appsettings.json used by the test project in the pipeline. If I put in the Azure connectionstring in the appsettings.json and commit it, it works as expected.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: You can set your connection string as environment variable in your pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start LocalDB on Azure DevOps will the following script

```yaml
- script: sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb
```

Comment: This command does not work, i added the following:

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'start mssqllocaldb'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb'

But i keep getting ' The term 'sqllocaldb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet'.

I its running on a 'Ubuntu-16.04' image. Could that be the isse?

Comment: Oh yeah, this is only installed on the windows images 

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace the LocalDB connectionString with Azure connectionstring in your pipeline. You can use variable substitution tasks(eg. [Magic Chunks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergeyzwezdin.magic-chunks) extension) to replace the connectionString in appsettings.json.

> First you need [set a variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline)(eg. MyConnectionString) in you pipeline to hold the value of Azure connectionstring.
>
> Then you can add **Config Transfromation Task** before the **Dotnet Test** Task, and refer to this variable using the syntax `$(MyConnectionString)` in the Config Transfromation Task to replace the LocalDB connectionString.

You can check out the example in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752866/updating-variables-in-web-config-outside-appsettings/58778660#58778660).

Another workaround is to use [self-host agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) to build your pipeline. Since Azure agents cannot communicate with your localDB, you can set up a self-hosted agent on your local machine. Your localDB is accesible to the self-hosted agent.

Hope above helps!