# Use KeyVaults variable group in unit test of pipeline

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, azure-devops

How I can use the value of this variable in my tests when are executed in the pipeline?

I am trying to get the values with the next configuration but with no success

Anyone with an example? or something to try?

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
               .AddUserSecrets<ExportReportsRunnerTest>()
               .AddEnvironmentVariables();

Configuration.GetSection("DevOpsSqlConnectionString").Value
Configuration.GetValue<string>("DevOpsSqlConnectionString")
```

[image: KeyVaults variable group]

Thanks in advance to everybody!

Comment: Well, an obvious problem is that DevOpsSqlConnectionString is **not** a Section. It's a key. Please refer to the documentation for .NET Core configuration..

Comment: Yes my fail but Configuration.GetValue<string>("DevOpsSqlConnectionString") doesn't work also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the tests in [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) in the pipeline. You can define the `DevOpsSqlConnectionString` parameter in the TestRunParameters section of [runsettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019) file, or Properties section of testsettings file.

Then you can specify the `overrideTestrunParameters` field of Visual Studio Test task to override the parameters defined in the runsettings or testsettings file with the variables in pipeline variable group. See below description of the `overrideTestrunParameters` field.

> Override parameters defined in the TestRunParameters section of runsettings file or Properties section of testsettings file.  For example: -key1 value1 -key2 value2

[image]

If you use `Dotnet test` to run your tests in pipeline. Or the DevOpsSqlConnectionString parameter is defined in some other config files. You can use the extension task [Magic Chunks](https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/magic-chunks) to override the parameters with variables in variable group before running the tests. You can aslo check out the example in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752866/updating-variables-in-web-config-outside-appsettings/58778660#58778660).

[image]