# FileTransform Task in release pipeline doesn't update the value - AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to update the value of `appsettings.Development.json` file while releasing application using Azure DevOps pipeline.

appSettings.Development.json

```
{
    "Networks": {
        "EnableNetwork": {
            "SomeNetwork": {
                "SomeValue": "Old Value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have configured **File Transform:** task as follows

[image]

And set the variable with scope "Release"

[image]

File Transfer Task runs successfully

[image]

However, it doesn't change the value after deployment. Tried different changes as shown in SO answers like [How to change Appsettings and Config info in Release Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64776651/4753489). But not sure where is the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps you use File Transform task should be correct. The value of appsettings.Development.json can be updated successfully.

You can check the log of File Transform task to confirm this point.

For example:

[image]

> it doesn't change the value after deployment.

From your screenshot, the cause of this issue could be that you are using Microsoft-hosted agent to deploy the IIS WebSite. It will deploy the website to hosted agent instead of your local machine.

[image]

According to your screenshot of the release pipeline definition, the Stage 3 should be run on Deployment Group. In this case, it will deploy the package to local machine.

You need to check the release pipeline definition to make sure the stage is running on Deployment Group. Then you will see the changes after deployment.

Comment: @DivyangDesai Can you edit the question and share the log of file transform task with us? This will help to investigate this issue.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I added Hosted Agent to test, I need to select deployment group instead. it works now.

Comment: Glad to know that it can work :) ! Have a nice day